# c++ opencv vector of vectors to mat without copying data

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, mat

I use the following function to train an svm:

```
void Trainer::train(const std::vector<std::vector<float>>& data, const std::vector<int>& labels) {

   cv::Mat trainData(data.size(), data.at(0).size(), CV_32FC1);

   for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
      for (int j = 0; j < data.at(0).size(); ++j)
          trainData.at<float>(i, j) = data.at(i).at(j);

   cv::Mat trainLabels(labels.size(), 1, CV_32FC1);

   for (int i = 0; i < labels.size(); ++i)
      trainLabels.at<float>(i) = static_cast<float>(labels.at(i));

   this->svm.train(trainData, trainLabels, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), this->params);

}
```

My problem is that `data` is really big and when I create the `trainData` `Mat` it just copying it's self. Is there any way to create a `Mat` out of a `vector` of `vectors` without copying?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't read the data directly into a `cv::Mat` in the first place, rather than building a vector of vectors?  Incidentally, vector of vectors can be exceedingly wasteful of memory unless you are very careful about how you build it.

Comment: if you can know what is the data size and dimension of each mat, you can create `trainData` and then copy each mat without using `vector` of `vectors` .... that is copying mats on the fly without pushing those on `vector` of `vectors`